# NHibernate Mapping-by-code One-To-One relationship: fetch by Join?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I have a table (`UncommittedVideoFile`) that has a strict one-to-one relationship with a  different table (`VideoOrImageAsset`). When I load an UncommittedVideoFile, I want to load the VideoOrImageAsset in the same query via a JOIN. (Inner or left outer).

Apparently it's possible to specify fetch-by-join when you use xml mapping: https://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one

It's also possible if you are using Fluent NHibernate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15694723/25216

But using MappingByCode, is is possible to set a Fetch option? I can't see one anywhere.

Here is the code that I currently have. The `IOneToOneMapper` interface does not have a `Fetch` method.

```
classMapper.OneToOne(
    f => f.VideoOrImageAsset,
    oneToOneMapper =>
    {
        oneToOneMapper.Constrained(true);
        oneToOneMapper.ForeignKey("Id");
        oneToOneMapper.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known missing mapping-by-code feature [GH-2139](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/2139). And it's already implemented in 5.3 (not yet released, but pretty [close](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/2388))

For now you can use pre-release version of 5.3 from https://www.myget.org/gallery/nhibernate (also check notes how to use it [here](https://nhibernate.info/blog/2020/05/11/nhibernate-myget-feed-available.html))